# Converting from json dump to utf8 and back to array in websocket connection

Tags: javascript, python, arrays, json, websocket

i have a websocket server running who is sending broadcasted messages to all connected clients. I am sending an python list via json dump encoded in utf8, how can I decode the utf8 message in the webbrwoser back to an array in javascript. Lets say my list looks like this:

Python on my websocket server:

```
>>> print Matrix
[[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], ['16001', 1, [], [], [], 0, [], [], []], ['16002', 2, [], [], [], [], [], [], []], ['16003', 3, [], [], [], [], [], [], 0]]
...
self.sendMessage(json.dumps(Matrix).encode('utf8'))
```

How can I decode this 'text'-message now in JavaScript into an Array, that looks exactly like on my Websocket Server?
Or is there any better solution to my problem?

Regards
Patrick

EDIT: 
from the browsers console I get this message recieved:

```
[[[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []], ["16001", 1, [], [], [], 0, [], [], []], ["16002", 2, [], [], [], [], [], [], []], ["16003", 3, [], [], [], [], [], [], 0]]
```

then:

```
result = JSON.parse(e.data)
```

returns after writing it to an object

```
,,,,,,,,,16001,1,,,,0,,,,16002,2,,,,,,,,16003,3,,,,,,,0
```

Comment: What is current result at `javascript`?

Comment: `JSON.parse`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse

Comment: the current result is an string, since websockets can only send messages as utf8 or binary

Comment: Yes. Can you include the current resulting string at Question?

Comment: It appears that calling `JSON.parse` is not necessary? As the array is returned? What does `console.log(Array.isArray(e.data), typeof e.data)` log? Or, are there quotes missing at string at updated Question? What is the `.binaryType` of `WebSocket` set to at `javascript`?

Comment: Sorry the quotes were missing .... binaryType is set to 'False', your JSON.parse suggestion works like a charm after playing around ... the problem was, I wrote the whole object to the Element. Writing something like `document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = result[1][0]` returns exactly what i want. Thank you!